# Count the number of riders in each category

Tags: python, csv

I have a code to get riders from certain teams and calculate the number of riders in those teams in that category:

```
valid_clubs = []
with open("validclubs.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        valid_clubs.append(line)


disqualification_reasons = ["WKG", "UPG", "ZP", "HR", "HEIGHT", "ZRVG", "new", "AGE", "DQ", "MAP", "20MINS", "5MINS"]


with open("results.csv", 'rt', encoding='UTF-8',errors='ignore') as file:  # open results file to get breakdown of results
    reader = csv.reader(file, skipinitialspace=True, escapechar='\\')
    # each variable is current number of riders in the category
    A = B = C = D = E = Q = W = 0  # setting all values to 0 so we can work out number of riders in each category
    for row in reader:
        try:
            category = row[0]
            if row[4] in valid_clubs:
                if row[7] == "0":  # if club is in valid_clubs.txt and gender = female
                    W = W + 1  # each time this condition is met increase value of W by 1, where W is the amount of women
                if "A" == category:  # if club is in valid_clubs.txt and category is A
                    A = A + 1  # each time this condition is met increase value of A by 1
                if "B" == category:  # if club is in valid_clubs.txt and category is B
                    B = B + 1  # each time this condition is met increase value of B by 1
                if "C" == category:  # if club is in valid_clubs.txt and category is C
                    C = C + 1  # each time this condition is met increase value of C by 1
                if "D" == category:  # if club is in valid_clubs.txt and category is D
                    D = D + 1  # each time this condition is met increase value of D by 1
                if category in disqualification_reasons:  # all the possible DQ reason
                    Q = Q + 1  # each time this condition is met increase value of Q by 1, where Q is the number of riders DQ'ed
                if "E" == category:  # if club is in valid_clubs.txt and category is E
                    E = E + 1  # each time this condition is met increase value of E by 1
        except IndexError:  # ignore errors where row is empty
            pass
        total = str(A + B + C + D + E + Q)
print("There were", total, "riders", W, " were women:", "\nCat A:", A, "\nCat B:", B, "\nCat C:",
      C, "\nCat D:", D, "\nCat E:", E, "\nDisqualified:", Q)
```

It is a really repetitive code and I'm sure could be cleaned up. I would appreciate some advice on how you would do this.

Here is an example CSV:

```
Category.Position,Name,Time,Team,RandomInt1,RandomInt2,Male?
A,1,Person 4,00:54:12.92,2281,343,4.4,1
A,2,Person 3,00:54:13.29,10195,310,4.2,1
A,3,Person 2,00:54:19.19,84,334,5.0,1
A,4,Person 1,00:54:19.33,7535,297,4.9,1
```

Category would change as you go down the CSV

The `Male?` column is 1 when the person is male and 0 when they are female,
Validclubs is a list of the team numbers which I want to use, imported from a txt file,
RandomInt1/RandomInt2 are irrelevant for now

I would appreciate any advice on reducing the code so it is cleaner/shorter.

I want to use built-in libraries so not pandas.

Comment: _not pandas_ - why not?

Comment: Please include your code that loads `valid_clubs`.

Comment: @Reinderien I have added now, on Pandas I have never worked with them, I have no knowledge of them so if I put this in and I want to make changes to my code I would not fully understand what it is doing

Comment: It's a useful thing to learn :) For small projects and datasets stock Python is fine, but you'll quickly run into performance issues when you try to scale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Set membership

```
valid_clubs = []
with open("validclubs.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        valid_clubs.append(line)
```

should be

```
with open("validclubs.txt") as f:
    valid_clubs = {line.strip() for line in f}
```

Lines coming back from a file handle in Python include their line ending, which you have to strip yourself; and you should be using a set, not a list. Set membership lookups will be much faster than list lookups.

### Consider `DictReader`

The `csv` module has a reader that gives you back a dictionary based on the headings, so that you do not have to write `row[0]`, but rather `row['Category']`.

### Use `Counter`

Your list of category `ifs` can be condensed to a one-liner; read about [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). This will be easier to use and perform better.

### Empty rows

Based on `# ignore errors where row is empty`, this should be done up-front. Rather than hitting your face on an `IndexError` and having to ignore it, simply check for an empty row:

```
if row:
```